# Umweltzone sticker for a car that matches restrictions but not age limit

Tags: germany, netherlands

I want to drive my car to the city of Stuttgart. I understand I need an umweltzone sticker for this.

According to ANWB (The place that distributes these stickers in the Netherlands) these are the possible requirements for the green stickers:

- Vehicle needs to be built after 31 december 1992
- Vehicle has emission norm Euro-1, Euro-2, Euro-3 or Euro-4.
- Vehicles with hybrid motors also get green stickers

'No sticker will be provided to cars built before 31 december 1992. If the car is built before this date and does have a motor with emission class Euro-2, you get a red sticker.'

Now, my car, a Porsche 911 964 built in 15 october 1992, goes by Euro norm 2. This model was built until late '93, and if it rolled out of the factory a few months later, it would have gotten a green sticker without any issues.

Now, I need this green sticker to enter Stuttgart. How can I make sure I get this green sticker, since my car passes all needed things except for the building date?

Comment: What mechanical requirements and dates are you referring to? To get a yellow environment sticker, your car must fulfill certain emission requirements. Mechanical properties or the date of production should be irrelevant.

Comment: A yellow sticker would not allow you to drive into Stuttgart. You'll need a green one.

Comment: How are you sure your car is suitable for Plakette? It's about motor model/type and not simply the output of some technical check.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo the Dutch website that lets you order the stickers has these requirements. Mechanical and emisison properties are listed as well.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo Because the car is also produced after the date I listed and it passes the emission and motor check if the date is correct. My car has exactly the same specs as the one produced 6 months later.

Comment: @Neusser Ah I thought a yellow one was sufficient. Quite weird you can't visit the Porsche factory and museum with your Porsche then...

Comment: Your question is getting more and more confusing. Are you saying that you are driving a Porsche? If so, which model? AFAIK, all Porsche model built in 96 or 97 should without modifications be able to get a green environment sticker.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Ok sorry, give me a minute to edit the question to clarify.

Comment: The answer should be, the only way to make sure, you need to apply for green thingie and either you get it or not. Everything else is a pure speculation.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo I just got a valid answer, but thanks.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 I hope it will work, just send your request ASAP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requirements you are quoting are simply wrong.

Petrol powered cars will either get a green environment sticker or no sticker at all. With very few exceptions, the only requirement is that the car is equipped with a three-way catalytic converter (TWC). A TWC became mandatory in many European countries in the late 80ies. In Germany, the requirement was not introduced until January 1st 1993. Maybe that is the source of the confusion. All petrol cars registered *in Germany on or after January 1st 1993* are automatically entitled to a green environment sticker, because the TWC required for a green sticker became mandatory for a registration on or after this date.

That does however not mean, that a registration before that date excludes the car from being issued a green sticker. A TWC had been required in many other countries long before the requirement was introduced in Germany and it is not uncommon that cars produced before 1993 are equipped with a TWC and fulfil the requirements for a green sticker. All variants of the Porsche 964 were equipped with a TWC and are eligible for the green sticker.

If ANWB refuses to issue a sticker based on false premises, there are several options for you to order the sticker from Germany. One option is [TÜV Süd](https://www.tuev-sued.de/auto_fahrzeuge/feinstaub-plakette/bestellen/england), which sells the sticker for 15€ incl. postage. You have to provide a scan of your registration certificate when ordering the sticker. You could also visit a TÜV Süd office on your way to Stuttgart and get the sticker for 6€.